# How to sort nested Firebase DB's nested object array

Tags: javascript, json

I have a JSON file like this:

```js
const presets = {
  key1: {
    val1: "asd",
    val2: "dsadd",
    singles: {
      likeCount: 23,
    },
  },
  key2: {
    val1: "asd2",
    val2: "dsadd2",
    singles: {
      likeCount: 100,
    },
  },
  key3: {
    val1: "asd3",
    val2: "dasad3",
    singles: {
      likeCount: 15,
    },
  },
  key4: {
    val1: "asd3",
    val2: "dasad3",
    singles: {
      likeCount: 80,
    },
  },
}
```

And I want to order this file by the `likeCount` property

Here's what I tried:

```js
Object.keys(presets)
  .map((key) => Object.assign({ key }, presets[key]))
  .sort((a, b) => b.singles.likeCount - a.singles.likeCount)
  .every((preset, index) => {
    fs.appendFile("./data.json", JSON.stringify(preset), () => {})
    return index < 20
  })
```

and the output:

```
[
  {
    "key": "key2",
    "val1": "asd2",
    "val2": "dsadd2",
    "singles": {
      "likeCount": 100
    }
  },
  {
    "key": "key4",
    "val1": "asd3",
    "val2": "dasad3",
    "singles": {
      "likeCount": 80
    }
  },
  {
    "key": "key1",
    "val1": "asd",
    "val2": "dsadd",
    "singles": {
      "likeCount": 23
    }
  },
  {
    "key": "key3",
    "val1": "asd3",
    "val2": "dasad3",
    "singles": {
      "likeCount": 15
    }
  }
]
```

The expected output:

```
{
  "key2": {
    "val1": "asd2",
    "val2": "dsadd2",
    "singles": {
      "likeCount": 100
    }
  },
  "key4": {
    "val1": "asd3",
    "val2": "dasad3",
    "singles": {
      "likeCount": 80
    }
  },
  "key1": {
    "val1": "asd",
    "val2": "dsadd",
    "singles": {
      "likeCount": 23
    }
  },
  "key3": {
    "val1": "asd3",
    "val2": "dasad3",
    "singles": {
      "likeCount": 15
    }
  }
}
```

My file's size is 80MB and after I sorted the data, file new file's size becomes 50MB. I mean, some of the data is also missing after the sorting.

My question: How can I sort an object like that without losing or changing anything on the data?

Comment: In JavaScript, you're not able to order keys in an object, which is what it looks like in the expected output. A function that is a sorted list by some value will have to be an array of objects as is your current output.

Comment: So first, I need to convert my object to an array, then sort the array and then reconvert it to object, right?

Comment: The idea behind an object being "sorted" in JavaScript is complex and can be [implementation-dependent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5467129/sort-javascript-object-by-key). Best practice dictates if possible, using an array for sorted items and an object if you need to index inside in constant time.

Comment: You can definitely sort the data in an array, but if you then convert it back to a regular object, you'll lost the sort order again.

Comment: @rb612 Keys are iterated over in insertion order if they are not numeric. The question you linked to says this as well.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen You won't lose the order if the keys are not numeric. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5525795/does-javascript-guarantee-object-property-order).

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen and @ hev1 good to know. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can sort `Object.entries` and convert it back to an object with `Object.fromEntries` as long as none of the keys are numeric, in which case they will be iterated over in insertion order.

```js
const presets = {
  key1: {
    val1: "asd",
    val2: "dsadd",
    singles: {
      likeCount: 23,
    },
  },
  key2: {
    val1: "asd2",
    val2: "dsadd2",
    singles: {
      likeCount: 100,
    },
  },
  key3: {
    val1: "asd3",
    val2: "dasad3",
    singles: {
      likeCount: 15,
    },
  },
  key4: {
    val1: "asd3",
    val2: "dasad3",
    singles: {
      likeCount: 80,
    },
  },
}
const res = Object.fromEntries(
     Object.entries(presets)
       .sort(([k1,v1],[k2,v2])=>v2.singles.likeCount - v1.singles.likeCount));
console.log(res);
```

Comment: I made it with lodash but your solution works too. I respect that. Thank you for your effort. This one is better!

Comment: @tpbafk Glad to help.